# background color of selected radio button does not change

Tags: jquery, css, html, radio-button

I do not intend to use the fieldset but using a span with radio buttons. Pretty new to html and jquery. I need to change the selected color of the radio button when it is checked. Am i using the wrong elements to show the radio button? Here' s the code:

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <span style="font-weight: bold;">Filter</span><br>
  <input backgroundColor="red" type="radio" name="filter" value="schedule">Schedule<br>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="risk">Risk<br>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="opm">OPM<br>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="location">Location<br>
  <input background-color="red" type="radio" name="filter" value="all" checked>All<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update HTML and add CSS to achieve this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Filter</span>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="schedule"><span>Schedule</span>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="risk"><span>Risk</span>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="opm"> <span>OPM</span>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="location"> <span>Location</span>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="all" checked><span>All</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input:checked + span {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1023/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: would really be better to use `label` instead of span for accessibility

Comment: Thanks @K K but i want the circle color to change on selection not the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=radio]:checked + span {
  background:gold;
}
```